# Rewrite field names in multiple tables - skipping over missing fields

Tags: ms-access, scripting, vba

I have an Access database with nearly 200 tables each with about 150 field. I need to change most of the field names and am writing some VBA code to programatically update the names to what I assign. The problem is that not all tables have exactly the same fields (some fields are missing from certain tables). Is there a way that I can write the change in the code, but just skip the change for a particular field if it doesn't exist in a particular table?

The basic code that I am using comes from this site: http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/125845-Change-Field-name-in-Table-with-VBA

And here is my actual code. I'm brand new to VBA, so please be gentle.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub changeFieldName()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim table As DAO.TableDef

Set db = CurrentDb
For 
Set table = db.TableDefs("table")

table.Fields("Field1").Name = "name1"
table.Fields("Field2").Name = "name2"
if(IsNull(table.Fields("FieldDoesn'tExist").Name = "name")) Then End If

Set table = Nothing
Next    

db.Close
Set db = Nothing


MsgBox "Changed"

End Sub
```

The "Then End If" statement doesn't work, but I don't know what to use here

Thanks for any help!
Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I'd approach it would be to put the old and new names into their own table named [NameMap]:

```
oldName   newName 
--------  --------
oldName1  newName1
oldName2  newName2
```

and then loop through that list to apply the name changes. The `On Error Resume Next` statement would allow the routine to continue if the table did not have a field whose name corresponded to one of the [oldName] values

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub changeFieldNames()
    Dim cdb As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, tbd As DAO.TableDef
    Set cdb = CurrentDb
    Set tbd = cdb.TableDefs("SampleTable")
    Set rst = cdb.OpenRecordset("SELECT oldName, newName FROM NameMap", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Do Until rst.EOF
        On Error Resume Next
        tbd.Fields(rst!oldName).Name = rst!newName
        On Error GoTo 0
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set tbd = Nothing
    Set cdb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, Gord! You just save me about 40 hours of work!